# How to disable an input field by using a programmatically computed id?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

this is how I create the input form

```
   var form_id = output.name;
   var input_id = output.name;

   $('<form>', {
        "id": form_id,
        "html": '<div class="input_field s12 l6"> <input id="' + input_id + '" name="' +  output.name + '" placeholder= ' + placeholder_text + '> </div> <div class="col s12 l6"><button class="btn blue" type="submit"> submit</button> </div>'
    }).appendTo(`.outputs_container`);
```

I'd need to enable/disable the input field in the form if some conditions are met.
The syntax to do it is:

```
document.getElementById('foo').disabled = true;
```

but if I do

```
document.getElementById(input_id).disabled = true;
```

the input field is not disabled.

How can I enable/disable the field by using a programmatically-computed id?

EDIT:
I've changed the input_id to be

```
input_id = output.name "_id";
```

and now it works!

Comment: The code should still work in that case. Either the value in `input_id` has changed between creating the element and trying to disable/enable it, or there are multiple elements in the DOM with the same `id`. As an aside, depending on the condition the element should be disabled under, it would be far better practice to use DOM traversal to find the element instead of using dynamic ids created at runtime.

Comment: I believe this is the way you do it with jquery, does this work `$("input").prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: @RolvApneseth If the underlying JS version isn't working, what makes you believe that a jQuery version would make any difference?

Comment: Very good point sorry

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you, I was using the same id for both the form and the input. Now it works!

Comment: tl;dr: Issue was that there were 2 elements with the same ID

Comment: @freedomn-m: yes, in the previous version of the question the `input_id` variable was different from the `form_id` but not in my actual code. I've edited the question by using my actual ids variable to make clear my mistake.